# Why is it automatically setting the value of the ID to black?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to create an "Order form" of sorts, and my goal is to make it so that when you select "black" on the dropdown list it will print out you have selected black. The only problem is it is automatically setting the value to black, so its always printing the statement. I am using JS and HTML:

JS:

```
    if(document.getElementById('tshirtd').value = 'Black'){
        document.getElementById('sent').innerHTML += "You've selected black!" + "<br>";
    }
 }
```

HTML:

```
<select id="tshirtd">
  <option value="default" id="default">Select</option>
  <option value="Black" id="black">Black</option>
  <option value="Red" id="red">Red</option>
  <option value="Blue" id="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="White" id="white">White</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `.value = 'Black'` is an assignment ... you want `.value == 'Black'` or `.value === 'Black'`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem i was having!

Answer (score 0):

You mistake comparing for assignment, so you can replace `=` with `===` in your if clause in JS.

```
    if (document.getElementById('tshirtd').value === 'Black'){
      document.getElementById('sent').innerHTML += "You've selected black!" + "<br>";
    }
```

Always better to use `===` which means a strict comparing in order to reduce a bug in variable type conversion.